# threeparttable unrecognized command

Tags: threeparttable, threeparttablex

I have the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{miscdoc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

And I have three tables like this one:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{ML Estimates pre ethanol boom period}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{1}$ CP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{2} $ CP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{1} $ EP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{2} $ EP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{1} $ OP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{2} $ OP} \\
    \midrule
    Estimate & 0.5515** & 0.1946 & 0.7614** & 0.1208 & 0.7325** & 0.1528 \\
    Std Error & 0.1494 & 0.0695 & 0.1593 & 0.0573 & 0.1196 & 0.0486 \\
    T-Stat & 3.6906 & 2.7995 & 4.7782 & 2.1098 & 6.1242 & 3.1425 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tablenotes}
                \small
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Double asterisks (**) represent significance at the 5\% level. 
    \item  Maximized Log-Likelihood =     1071.1
    \item $\delta_{1}=0.9409 (0.1014)$ and  $\delta_{2}=0.0125 (0.0132)$  
    \item $df=8.86$

   \end{enumerate}
    \end{tablenotes}
```

The `\begin{tablenotes}` and  `\end{tablenotes}`  it says unrecognized command and it compiles but is marked as an error and doesn't let me change between pages. Can someone help me please

Comment: Please make a complete document that shows the error, not two disconnected fragments.

Comment: Please edit the question above so there is just one code fragment not two and the example starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` so that if we copy the example and run it locally we get the error message in the question. That makes it _much_ easier to say why you are getting an error message. "says unrecognized command " is not the exact error message and we can not reproduce the error from the code posted so it is impossible to guess your problem without more information.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `enumerate` inside `tablenotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{ML Estimates pre ethanol boom period}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{1}$ CP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{2} $ CP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{1} $ EP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{2} $ EP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{1} $ OP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{2} $ OP} \\
    \midrule
    Estimate & 0.5515** & 0.1946 & 0.7614** & 0.1208 & 0.7325** & 0.1528 \\
    Std Error & 0.1494 & 0.0695 & 0.1593 & 0.0573 & 0.1196 & 0.0486 \\
    T-Stat & 3.6906 & 2.7995 & 4.7782 & 2.1098 & 6.1242 & 3.1425 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \item[1] Double asterisks (**) represent significance at the 5\% level.
    \item[2]  Maximized Log-Likelihood =     1071.1
    \item[3] $\delta_{1}=0.9409 (0.1014)$ and  $\delta_{2}=0.0125 (0.0132)$
    \item[4] $df=8.86$
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @HarishKumar has already pointed out, don't embed the `\item`s of the `tablenotes` environment in an `enumerate` section. (In case you're curious: they're already embedded in an `itemize` environment.) In addition, since the table notes don't appear to be linked directly to any specific part of the `tabular` material, I'd load the `threeparttable` package with the option `flushleft`. Finally, I'd line up the numbers on their decimal markers. This can be done by loading the `dcolumn` package and its `D` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}  % commented out all packages not needed for the MWE
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{miscdoc}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{ML Estimates pre ethanol boom period}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{d{1.6} d{1.4}} @{}}
    \toprule
          & \mc{$\lambda_{1}$ CP} & \mc{$\lambda_{2}$ CP} & \mc{$\lambda_{1}$ EP} 
          & \mc{$\lambda_{2}$ EP} & \mc{$\lambda_{1}$ OP} & \mc{$\lambda_{2}$ OP} \\
    \midrule
    Estimate  & 0.5515^{**} & 0.1946 & 0.7614^{**} & 0.1208 & 0.7325^{**} & 0.1528 \\
    Std Error & 0.1494 & 0.0695 & 0.1593 & 0.0573 & 0.1196 & 0.0486 \\
    T-Stat    & 3.6906 & 2.7995 & 4.7782 & 2.1098 & 6.1242 & 3.1425 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

  \begin{tablenotes}
   \small
    \item Double asterisks ($^{**}$) represent significance at the 5\% level. 
    \item  Maximized Log-Likelihood${} = 1071.1$
    \item $\delta_{1}=0.9409\ (0.1014)$ and  $\delta_{2}=0.0125\ (0.0132)$  
    \item $df=8.86$
    \end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```